# Pythonic way to find if a string contains multiple values?

Tags: python, string, find

I am trying to find through a list of files all the `excel`, `txt` or `csv` files and append them to a list

```
goodAttachments = [i for i in attachments if str(i).split('.')[1].find(['xlsx','csv','txt'])
```

This is obviously not working because `find()` needs a string and not a list. Should I try a list comprehension inside of a list comprehension?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no need to split or use double list comprehension. You can use `str.endswith` which takes a tuple of strings to check as an argument:

```
goodAttachments = [i for i in attachments if str(i).endswith(('.xlsx', '.csv', '.txt'))]
```

If you really want to split:

```
goodAttachments = [i for i in attachments if str(i).split('.')[-1] in ('xlsx', 'csv', 'txt')]
```

The first way is better as it accounts for files with no extension.

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this:

```
goodAttachments = [i for i in attachments if str(i).split('.')[-1] in ['xlsx', 'csv', 'txt']]
```

This will check if the extension after the last '.' matches one of 'xlsx', 'csv', or 'txt' exactly.

Answer (score 0):

```
[i for i in attachments if any([e in str(i).split('.')[1] for e in ['xlsx','csv','txt']]))
```

Like you said, nested list comprehension.

Edit: This will work without splitting, I was trying to replicate the logic in `find`.

Answer (score 0):

You can check that everything after the last dot is present in a second list.  using `[-1]` instead of `[1]` ensures that files named `like.this.txt` will return the last split `txt` and not `this`.

```
goodAttachments = [i for i in attachments if str(i).split('.')[-1] in ['xlsx','csv','txt']]
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest maybe adding a few more lines then trying to create a one-liner with nested list comprehensions. Though that would work, I think it makes more readable code to split these comprehensions out onto separate lines.

```
import os

attachments = ['sadf.asdf', 'asd/asd/asd.xslx']
whitelist = {'.xslx', '.csv'}

extentions = (os.path.split(fp)[1] for fp in attachments)
good_attachments = [fp for fp, ext in zip(attachments, extentions) if ext in whitelist]
```

I've also used `os.path.split` over `str.split` as the file may have multiple dots present and this split is designed for this exact job.